# How the compiler is giving this answer?

Tags: c++

I made a program and made a small mistake of declaring an array of structure like in this program as `node o[no];` not as `node *o=new node[no];` The result when i got from executing this buggy code was little different. I have compiled and gave input zero and it gave output zero when last two lines were commented.

```
shizuka@naruto:~$ g++ -std=c++11 hours.cpp
shizuka@naruto:~$ ./a.out
2
0shizuka@naruto:~$
```

When i uncommented those lines, the output changed to:

```
shizuka@naruto:~$g++ -std=c++11 hours.cpp
shizuka@naruto:~$ ./a.out
2
2ABCABCshizuka@naruto:~$
```

Then i put that `cout>> count>>"\n";` inside outer loop (in last two line commented code) to see what was happening [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).
Then i uncommented the last two lines and ran it again [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YkhHzRBi). Output is different. Not getting how can count variable is affected by commenting and uncommenting last two lines of code.

**Basically i want to know how this wrong way of declaring array of structure affecting the value stored in variable `count`.**

It is working all fine with `node *o=new node[no];` instead of `node o[no];`

This program is to find number of integer co-ordinate inside the circle of radius r with centre at 0.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct node{
        int x;int y;
    };
    int main()
    {
        int r;
        cin >> r;
        int no=2*r+1;
        //node *o=new node[no];
        node o[no];
        int count=0;
        cout << r<< endl;
        for(int i=-r;i<=r;i=i+1)
        {
            for(int j=-r;j<=r;j=j+1)
            {
                int k=i*i+j*j;
                if( k <= (r*r) )
                {
                    o[count].x=i;
                    o[count++].y=j;     
                }
            }
        }
        cout << count;
        //for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        //  cout<<"ABC";
        return 0;   

    }
```

Comment: Have you heard the term *undefined behavior*? If not, Google it. And after that, turn on hints and warnings for your compiler.

Comment: if they are alternatives, then I would rather call it a mistake to write `node *o=new node[no];` instead of `node o[no];`. However, as `no` isnt a constant, the code should not even compile (unless your compiler has that nasty variable length extension)

Comment: When `no` is not a constant expression, `node o[no];` is not standard C++ and should be avoided.

Comment: `node o[no];` is not valid C++. Set your standard to `-std=c++14` or something like that to avoid that error in the future.

Comment: Note that you can use `std::vector<node> o( no )`. This has the added advantage of coming with an iterator library, which then can be used with real higher-order functions instead of buggy imperative loops

Comment: I got it that it was undefined behaviour . But how is value of count is zero for all input for this code and something else when last two commented lines are uncommented? I was curious that's all?

Comment: Undefined is undefined - *anything* can happen. When you write out-of-bounds you overwrite some other data, perhaps `count`, perhaps `cout`, perhaps the number `2`? Depending on how you allocate memory you will destroy different parts of the program, which of course might give you different results.

Comment: Undefined behavior is an answer in itself. But for completion sake, when you say that the automatic array fails while the dynamic one """works""", I'm going to assume the automatic array was allocated on the stack, and your code managed to overwrite local parameters

Comment: @KABoissonneault I got it. It means somehow local parameters were overwritten. Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick:  The *compiler* translates your code into an executable and may spit out error messages.  The output you are referring to came from *executing your program*, not the compiler.

Comment: You should assign `r * r` to a constant variable before the `for` loop since the expression doesn't change inside either `for` loop.  This could improve your program's performance.

Comment: Also, calculate `i * i` before starting the `for j` loop.  The value of `i * i` does not change inside the `j` loop.